# Word/phrase/idiom that means "deliberately chosen"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Example:

> The books in this library were extremely colorful, almost as if they'd been
>   [...] to fit the contemporary feel of the library.

Maybe *hand-picked*? That's the only word I can think of. But I'm not sure whether it's a suitable choice.

Comment: 'designed' is a possible and not just with its most obvious meaning. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/design *Do or plan (something) with a specific purpose in mind:*

Comment: I've been trying to work out how something could be other than 'deliberately' chosen. But the word is not redundant here. It means **specifically**: _The books in this library were extremely colorful, almost as if they'd been [deliberately chosen / chosen specifically] to fit the contemporary feel of the library._ Now I have to work out why the position changes. And why 'hand-picked' works while 'picked' sounds weak here.

Comment: carefully chosen / as if someone had them ordered through a catalogue or an interior design magazine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use 'hand-selected' over 'hand-picked' in this case, but I think either would work. Perhaps also 'cherry-picked' or 'curated'?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just one question: why "selected" works better than "picked" even though they basically have the same meaning?

Comment: @Patrick, earn respect and applause by editing your excellent answer to include a definition (e.g. past tense: selected; past participle: selected     carefully chosen as being the best or most suitable) and a reference (e.g. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/select ) [please swipe and paste to make your own edit]

Comment: Selected implies a careful or thoughtful choice.  Picked is more casual, intuitive.

Comment: Is this a real example?  Who picks books on the basis of their color?  Yes, I know the noveau riche used to order books by the yard, literally, to populate their shelves.  Off-topic, but it had to be said.

Comment: @ab2 you'd be surprised how many [color coded bookcases](https://www.google.it/search?q=color+coordinated+bookcase&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CCEQsARqFQoTCKOfsLjomMcCFYRpFAodgcQNQQ&biw=1366&bih=677#tbm=isch&q=color+coded+bookcase) there are see also: https://www.google.it/search?q=color+coordinated+bookcase&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CCEQsARqFQoTCKOfsLjomMcCFYRpFAodgcQNQQ&biw=1366&bih=677

Comment: Gah.  (also, nouveau)